# Telegram Telethon download media

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telethon

I'm trying to figure out how telethon works.
it has a good documentation but I don't understand how download a video from telegram group.
I created a telegram group for test pourpose. I uploaded a video (from desktop client).
This code should starts to download the video on message events.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.tl.types import InputMessagesFilterVideo

import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='[%(levelname) 5s/%(asctime)s] %(name)s: %(message)s',
                    level=logging.WARNING)


api_id = #########
api_hash = "#######################"
client = TelegramClient('desktop', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if 'hello' in event.raw_text:
        await event.reply('hi!')

    channel_username = '######'

    message = await client.get_messages(channel_username, limit=10)
    await message[0].download_media("Video.mp4")

    #video = await client.get_messages(chat, 0, filter=InputMessagesFilterVideo)
    #print(video.total)

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Error:
AttributeError: 'TotalList' object has no attribute 'download_media'

Attribute doesn't exist , but I dont know how get the right ref
Thanks for help

EDIT : updated to

```
await message[0].download_media("Video.mp4")
```

Comment: TotalList is a list of messages, you have to choose an index like [0]

Comment: Thanks it returns no errors, but it writes no file on hdd. I tested it with filter and the video exists in chat

Comment: When you change your code and that changes the error (or bad behaviour) you should update both code and error in you question.
You should log some info around `message[0]` to understand what it is. Maybe that is not the message with the video. Maybe store the result of `download_media` in a variable - if it is `None` there was a problem.